# Ruby on Rails- Query Amount between two dates from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, console

I want to query total amount (which is a column in all the records) and have an option to choose dates to get the sum of the amount between those dates.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sum`:

```
Model.sum(:amount)
```

To select dates, just add `where`:

```
Model.where(date: from_date..to_date).sum(:amount)
```

Comment: Thaks Garry, I tried what you have suggested, However it's not working 

***a.account.where(date: Mon, 27 Feb 2017..Fri, 31 Mar 2017).sum(:amount)***

SyntaxError: unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
a.account.where(date: Mon, 27 Feb 2017..Fri, 31 Mar 2017).sum(:amount)

Comment: @rail_engine You need to use either a `DateTime` object or a string in _yyyy-mm-dd_ format. For example, try with `a.account.where(date: "2017-02-27".."2017-03-31").sum(:amount)`.